# Given $\phi:R\to R/N$, why is the image of a proper ideal containing $N$ proper in $R/N$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

Under the map

$$\phi:R\rightarrow R/N$$
                                     $$r\rightarrow r+N$$
where $R$ is a field and $N$ is an ideal of $R$.
it is a well known facts that the image of an ideal is again an ideal and the inverse image of an ideal is again an ideal(under a homomorphism).

now why would the image under $\phi$ of a proper non trivial ideal that properly contains $N$ is again a proper non trivial ideal.

Comment: It's not. Consider the image of $N$. Also the only ideal of a field not containing the identity is the zero ideal

Comment: my bad i forgot to mention that it properly contains N

Comment: and yup the image of N is a trivial ideal in R/N

Comment: my guess is if our ideal M properly contains N then it follows that it's image can't be the trivial ideal in R/N and since our ideal is closed under addition it follows that r+N can't spawn all of R/N for all r in M because for each r in M r+N will only provide a set with elements only in M

Comment: Let $I$ be such an ideal. Then there exists $x \in I-N$, so the image of $x$ is nonzero. To see that $\phi(I) \neq R/N$, note that $1$ is not in the image of $I$. Otherwise $I$ would contain the unit in $R$

Comment: eh.. what says that if 1 is in the image of I then I should contain the unit in R

Comment: i mean if it was a one to one function sure but that doesn't seem to be the case here

Comment: It means $1+N=r+N$ for some $r \in I$. But then there is some $n\in  N$ such that $1=r-n$. But $N \subseteq I$...

Comment: alrighty i get it  now, thanx for the assistance

Comment: Hello: please title your questions usefully. I have changed your title to something useful. As a rule, it is a waste of time to parrot the tags in the titles.  Quite often the actual question (or a shortened version) is a much better choice.  good luck

Comment: @leibnewtz Please avoid answering questions in the comments.

Comment: @PedroTamaroff You're right, my comment turned into an answer before I knew it

Comment: @leibnewtz Sorry, I should have been more direct. Could you turn your comment into an answer? :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $I$ be an ideal of $R$ properly containing $N$, i.e. $N \subseteq I$ and $N  \neq I$. Let $J \subseteq R/N$ be the image of $I$ under the projection $\pi: R \to R/N$. To see that $J \neq 0$, choose $x \in I-N$. Then $\pi(x) \neq 0$ in $R/N$ since $x+N=0+N$ implies that $x \in N$. To see that $J \neq R/N$, I claim that $\pi(1) \notin J$. If it was we could write $1=r+n$ for some $r \in I$ and $n \in N$. But $N \subseteq I$ which implies $1 \in I$, a contradiction.